How to calculate a local variable in function_1 and send the result to function_2 without running function_1 every time function_2 is called?
I'm trying to design a card game with a 'shuffle' function and a 'deal' function. The problem I'm encountering is that every time I pass the results of 'shuffle' to 'deal', the cards are shuffled. I'm new to local variables... how can I pass the local variable from 'shuffle' to 'deal' when I only want the 'shuffle' effect calculated once?
Here is a simplified example of what I've tried:
import random

def shuffle():
    x = random.randrange(1, 11)
    return x

def deal():
    x = shuffle()
    print('\nx =', x)
    inpt = input('\nEnter anything to deal again, or x to quit: ')
    if inpt == 'x':
        quit()

while True:
    deal()

I want 'deal' to print out a consistent value of x, but instead it is shuffled for every iteration. How can I shuffle x just once so that x is printed as a consistent value?
*note: I know I could simplify this code by making it just one function, but I need help understanding how local variables move between functions. Thanks

what is the condition that determines that you want to shuffle again?

I've been told to avoid using global variables so I'm trying to define my variables within functions. I'm not sure how to get the result from shuffle from shuffle() to deal() without running shuffle() every time

This is probably incredibly simple if you just answer my question.

@pmac global variables are fine as long as you use them to pass into other functions as arguments. You were probably told to avoid to use the global keyword, which would allow access to global variables within a function.

If you really wanted to avoid using global variables, you could probably construct a class CardGame which includes the methods shuffle and deal.

Move the while into the deal() function. Then call shuffle() once then enter the loop.

@OysterShucker I've constructed it differently in my actual program-- there is a shuffle() that the user can call during their turn(). I couldn't make the simplified version I submitted in my question work, though, so I thought I'd pare it back to the basics.

It is because you have called shuffle from the deal method. Something like this should give you what you're looking for.
import random

def shuffle():
    x = random.randrange(1, 11)
    return x

def deal(x):
    # x = shuffle()
    print('\nx =', x)
    inpt = input('\nEnter anything to deal again, or x to quit: ')
    if inpt == 'x':
        quit()

x = shuffle()

while True:
    deal(x)

Alternatively you could move the while True: into the deal method.
import random

def shuffle():
    x = random.randrange(1, 11)
    return x

def deal():
    x = shuffle()
    while True:
        print('\nx =', x)
        inpt = input('\nEnter anything to deal again, or x to quit: ')
        if inpt == 'x':
            quit()

deal()


that's a global variable. The OP wants to study local variables.

That will deal the same card forever.

@jlandercy did you read the post? "I want 'deal' to print out a consistent value of x" (emphasis mine)

Thank you! My issue is trying to understand when and how to use local vs global variables. I've been told to avoid global variables, but I supple in this case it's ok to use a global variable as a placeholder?

@pmac read my comment on your question. tldr: you were probably told to avoid the usage of the global keyword.

@pmac, I just added an alternative if you should not be using globals you can move the while loop into the deal method.

The fact that this is the accepted answer is rather bizarre as it uses a global variable which OP clearly stated was to be avoided

Well one way you can do it is to first modify deal() to accept some argument, let's say it's called shuffle_value, which will act in place of x in your example code. Then have some global variable be assigned a value from shuffle() which will then be passed into the deal function. This way, shuffle is only called once on the global scope, which will keep the value consistent throughout all calls of deal.
If that was a bit confusing, here is the actual code:
import random

def shuffle():
    x = random.randrange(1, 11)
    return x

def deal(shuffle_value): # takes in an argument "shuffle_value"
    print('\nx =', shuffle_value) # notice that shuffle_value took the place of x
    inpt = input('\nEnter anything to deal again, or x to quit: ')
    if inpt == 'x':
        quit()

shuffle_value = shuffle() # global variable which is assigned a value from shuffle()

while True:
    deal(shuffle_value) # pass in the global variable "shuffle_value"


This is the exact same answer as @BenD with x renamed to shuffle_value. Also, the OP is trying to study local variables, what you have illustrated is a global variable.

Very clear, thank you!

@OysterShucker OP wants to study "how local variables move between functions," which can be best achieved by utilizing a global variable.

That may be the most ridiculous thing I've read all day.

@OysterShucker so what is your genius plan to solve OP's problem then?

If they would answer my question I would tell you. It's a really simple question and it has gone completely ignored. What is the damn condition to shuffle again.

@OysterShucker Well it seems like they only want to shuffle once at the start, and then keep the value consistent afterwards.

Use functools.cache
In that way the shuffle() function will always return the same (original) value.
import random
from functools import cache

@cache
def shuffle():
    x = random.randrange(1, 11)
    return x

def deal():
    x = shuffle()
    print('\nx =', x)
    inpt = input('\nEnter anything to deal again, or x to quit: ')
    if inpt == 'x':
        quit()

while True:
    deal()

Subsequently, if you want shuffle() to return a (potentially) new value, just call shuffle.cache_clear()
